# How to speed up IndexReader.open

Tags: java, lucene

When I use DirectoryReader.open to open some directory of over 100G,but it opened a long time.(lucene 4.2)
  Can somebody advise me what policy/optimization I should use to speed readers open?
  Perhaps when indexing should be noted.

Maybe I'm not clear enough description.

Every day more than 70 million data to be indexed.
  For each index database storage space is 40G.
  If the retrieval support within one month.(30*40G,In fact the need to support longer)I have to open all the indexReader, add them to MultiReader and reuse them.Open them very slow.I only know that set IndexWriter's mergeFactor values. (Large values speed up indexing but increase the number of files that need to be opened simultaneously.)I can set up a  small value to optimize.Are there any other parameters or solutions.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Have you merged the index lately?

Comment: yes,I try to set the IndexWriter's mergeFactor values

Answer (score 2):

Opening an `IndexReader` is a costly operation.  It's generally better to keep the same IndexReader around and reuse it.  You can keep it current by calling [`DirectoryReader.openIfChanged`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/DirectoryReader.html#openIfChanged%28org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader%29):

```
IndexReader newReader = DirectoryReader.openIfChanged(oldReader)
if (newReader == null) {
    readerToUse = oldReader;
} else {
    readerToUse = newReader;
    oldReader.close(); //Make sure you close the old one!!
```

Even when there are changes to the index and a new reader is generated, this will still usually be a lot less costly than `DirectoryReader.open`.

Comment: yes,it really a is a costly operation.But the speed of open I can't accept.But I had to open.